# Windows Phone Toolkit Download

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-phone

I am new bee for windows phone development. I have windows 7 OS and visual studio 2010. 
I just want to know is there any windows phone toolkit support Windows 7 and Visual studio 2010.

If yes then please give me link where I can download windows phone toolkit which is supported by Windows 7 OS and Visual Studio 2010

Thanks in advance.

Patel Azharuddin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to develop phone apps for Windows Phone 7, 7.5, you can do so with the help of Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone SDK.You can download from here,

[`WP7 SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

[`Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-phone-7-developer-tools-released)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're developing for Windows Phone 7 and 7.5, and I really can't see the point of doing that, you will need Windows 8 in order to develop using the [Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).

If you can't, or don't want to install Windows 8 on your computer, you can also consider running [a virtual machine](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator). This link provides a very nice tutorial how to setup a Windows Phone development on a virtual machine.